# VBA: Create ID for Corresponding Questions (With repeating rows)

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a questionnaire in Excel using VBA, and each question needs a unique identifier. However, the multiple choice answers each have a row each, so the question ID should repeat for those options. Also, in a different column, the multiple choice answers also need their own identifier. The data needs to look like this:

| Column A: Question | Column T: Questionnaire Code | Column U: Single Question Code | Column AX: Option Code | Column AY: Options |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | ABC1 | ABC1_001 |  |  |
| Age | ABC1 | ABC1_002 |  |  |
| Location | ABC1 | ABC1_003 | ABC1_003_1 | England |
| Location | ABC1 | ABC1_003 | ABC1_003_2 | France |
| Location | ABC1 | ABC1_003 | ABC1_003_3 | Spain |
| Individual | ABC1 | ABC1_004 | ABC1_004_1 | John |
| Individual | ABC1 | ABC1_004 | ABC1_004_2 | Jane |
| Individual | ABC1 | ABC1_004 | ABC1_004_3 | Jack |
| Individual | ABC1 | ABC1_004 | ABC1_004_4 | Jay |
| Pass/Fail | ABC1 | ABC1_005 | ABC1_005_1 | Pass |
| Pass/Fail | ABC1 | ABC1_005 | ABC1_005_2 | Fail |

My Macro so far is able to automatically load in Col A and Col T, but I am unable to create the code for columns U and AX.

All I need is for Col U to increase by 1 every question, but repeat when there are multiple options; and Column AX to remain blank unless there are multiple rows of choices - in which each choice gets a unique identifier.

Any help or guidance at all would be **hugely** appreciated - I just can't seem to get my code to work.

Apologies if there's a lack of detail due to data privacy reasons, which is also why I can't include any of the code. If it helps, it looks similar to this:

```
Sub Qest()
Dim Ssh As Worksheet, Tsh As Worksheet
Set Ssh = Worksheets("NA")
Set Tsh = Worksheets("NA2")
k = 3
lastquest = Ssh.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastquest
  
  answerarray = Split(Ssh.Cells(i, 5), ", ")  
   
  For j = 0 To UBound(answerarray)
  
    'Col A:
        Tsh.Cells(k, "A") = Ssh.Cells(i, "D")
    'Col T:
        Tsh.Cells(k, "T") = Ssh.Cells(i, "F")

     '*insert Single Q and Option Code here*

    
    k = k + 1
    
  
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use two `Dictionary` objects to count the question and option

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144121)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic1 As Object, objDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, lastRow As Long, sQuesCode As String
    Const COL_LAST = "AY"
    Const COL_QUES = 1 ' A, Quest
    Const COL_CODE = 20 ' T, Quest Code
    Const COL_SCODE = 21 ' U, Single Quest Code
    Const COL_OCODE = 50 ' AX, Option Code
    ' Load data into an array
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("A2", .Cells(lastRow, COL_LAST))
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, COL_QUES) & "|" & arrData(i, COL_CODE)
        If objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic1(sKey) = objDic1(sKey) + 1
        Else
            objDic1(sKey) = 1
        End If
        sQuesCode = arrData(i, COL_CODE) & "_" & Format(objDic1.Count, "000")
        ' Column U: Single Question Code
        arrData(i, COL_SCODE) = sQuesCode
        If objDic2.exists(sQuesCode) Then
            objDic2(sQuesCode) = objDic2(sQuesCode) + 1
        Else
            objDic2(sQuesCode) = 1
        End If
        ' Column AX: Option Code
        arrData(i, COL_OCODE) = sQuesCode & "_" & objDic2(sQuesCode)
    Next i
    ' Clean Column AX: Option Code
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sQuesCode = arrData(i, COL_SCODE)
        If objDic2(sQuesCode) = 1 Then arrData(i, COL_OCODE) = ""
    Next
    ' Write data to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you so much - lifesaver! The only issue I'm still encountering is that it's starting at row 2 instead of row 3, and replacing the column headings as a result. How would I go about changing that without breaking the macro?

Comment: Just figured it out! Thank you for all your help

Comment: Hey - thanks again for this. I am wondering how one might change this code to remove duplicates in column U? So only the first entry for each multiple choice Q has the single question code, and the rest of the options are blank?